# Where does this XAML exception come from?

Tags: c#, xaml

I use a binding group to check input parameters. Suddenly I get an Exception thrown in XAML. OK, here we go with some code I think might be relevant. First a piece of the XAML:

```
<Grid
     x:Name="TopGrid"
     DockPanel.Dock="Top"
     Height="269">
     <Grid.BindingGroup>
          <BindingGroup
               Name="LengthBindingGrp"
               NotifyOnValidationError="True">
               <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                  <c:LengthValidationRule
                     ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" />
               </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
           </BindingGroup>
     </Grid.BindingGroup>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And this is the validation routine:

```
     public class LengthValidationRule : ValidationRule
        {
            public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
            {
                BindingGroup bindingGroup = (BindingGroup)value;

                CableViewModel cvm = ((CableViewModel)bindingGroup.Items[0]);            
                double x = cvm.RHSupportX;

                if (x < 0)
                    return new ValidationResult(false, Resources.RHSupport_Right);
                if (cvm.RHSupportY < 0)
                    return new ValidationResult(false, Resources.RHSupportNotHigher);

                ObservableCollection<LoadCombi> loads = cvm.Loads;

                foreach (LoadCombi ld in loads)
                {
                    if (ld.Position < 0 || (ld.Position > x && !ld.Fixed) || (ld.Fixed && ld.Position > cvm.Ucl))
                        return new ValidationResult(false, String.Format(Resources.LoadPosition, ld.Position ));
                }

                return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            }
}
```

Then I get this error screen in XAML:

```
    InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '_.di1.CableCalc.CableViewModel' to type 'CableCalc.CableViewModel'.

Stack Trace
    at CableCalc.LengthValidationRule.Validate(Object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule.Validate(Object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo, BindingGroup owner)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup.CheckValidationRules()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingGroup.UpdateAndValidate(ValidationStep validationStep)
       at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.DelayedValidateWithoutUpdate(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

The error seems to have originated in the line

```
CableViewModel cvm = ....
```

Because there I do a casting.

But somehow this worked before. What did I do to get this exception in XAML?

Comment: Is it possible that there are two classes (in different namespaces) called `CableViewModel`?

Comment: Are you using an extension like Resharper to auto modify the namespaces?

Comment: @Odrai: No. I used it a week ago but got rid of it.

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen: indeed was messing something up with CableViewModel as DataContext. I set it as DC in XAML and in Code Behind. That does not fly. PluralSight video on MVVM was helpful too.